Resized an array in a function but when it returned it was its original size
I pass an array into a function in a separate cs file where I resize the array. when I return the array and check its length in my main file it is the size it was before. I have absolutely no clue what to do.
    //this is the code in my main file
    string[] Names = new string[0];

    selectCode.namesSetup(Names);

    //and this is the code in my file where the function is located
    public string[] namesSetup(string[] Names)
    {
        Array.Clear(Names, 0, Names.Length);
        Array.Resize(ref Names, 65);

        return Names;
    }


You should generally avoid using arrays if you need to resize them. Without context, it's hard to know whether this would be better in your case but you should generally use a collection rather than an array, so it will just grow and shrink as you Add and Remove items. In this case, that would mean a List<string>.

You cannot actually resize an array. Arrays are a fixed size. That Array.Resize method actually creates a new array of the specified size and copies the elements from the old one to the new. That's why the first parameter is declared ref: because it needs to refer to a different object coming out than going in. Because the parameter in your own namesSetup is not declared ref, assigning a new object to it inside the method has no effect on the variable you pass in.
The thing is, your method actually returns the new array but you are ignoring the return value. Your code can work without changing that method simply by doing this:
Names = selectCode.namesSetup(Names);

Alternatively, you could change the method to this:
public void namesSetup(ref string[] Names)
{
    Array.Clear(Names, 0, Names.Length);
    Array.Resize(ref Names, 65);
}

and then call it like this:
selectCode.namesSetup(ref Names);

